# Multiple wives of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, lakshmi

So I have always grown up having Vishnu and Lakshmi in my mind and seen them represented as a couple. In my mind, Lakshmi has always been Vishnupriya.

I am South Indian but was not aware about Bhu Devi for the longest time and even less so about a 3rd wife, apparently! Nila Devi. I also see that this representation of Sri, Bhu and Nila is more particular to South India.

So where have these legends come from? Is it from tradition/folk lore or from the Vedas? Why isn’t Bhudevi much mentioned in North India as Vishnu’s wife? Was Satyabhama her avatar - I thought it was Krishna who killed Narakasura!

Also, what is the source of the prayer - samudra Vasane Devi?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Bhumi Devi is wife of Vishnu and Narakasura was their son -

*When I was lifted by you, O Lord, in your boar incarnation, this son (Naraka) was born of me in consequence of your contact. So you gave that son to me and now he has been struck down by you.*

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1128933.html

It was Lord Krishna himself who killed Narakasura -

*His attempt having been thus frustrated, Naraka, the son of the Earth goddess, took up his spear to strike at Kṛṣṇa, but before he could hurl it, Hari, with his discus (Sudarśana) of razor-like sharp edge, severed the head of Naraka who was riding on elephant.*

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1128933.html

Comment: Thank you! One question - which scripture says that Varaha married Bhu Devi? The Bhagavata Purana mentions only that there was a son from contact but not a marriage or that she is a form of Lakshmi.

Answer (score 0):

Sita Upanishad.:

> 11-13. That divine Being (Sita) is threefold through Her power, namely the power of desire, the power of action, and the power of knowledge.  The power of desire is threefold: **Sri (Lakshmi), Bhumi and Nila.** Auspiciousness is the form (of Sri); the power (of holiness) is the form (of Bhumi); the sun, the moon, and the fire are the forms (of Nila).  As the moon (She) is the mistress of the herbs; She is the tree of plenty, flowers, fruits, creepers and bowers; the mistress of medicinal plants and physicians; She is the divine draught of immortality, yielding the fruit of massive splendour. She satisfies the gods with ambrosia and the animals with grass on which, respectively, the gods and the animals live.

In Sri Kalika Upa Purana Chapter Sarasar Nirupam Mata Prithvi is called as Varahi the wife of Lord Varaha.

> Lord Varaha himself had gone to a mountain named Lokalok and **there he started living with his wife Varahi, who was the most beautiful lady Earth (Prithvi).**

Sri Brahma Vaivarta Purana Sri Radha-Krsna-samvada.:

> 143. Saintly Savitri, the mother of the Vedas, will be named Nagnajiti. **Vasundhara (Earth) will become Satyabhama.** Goddess Sarasvati will become Saibya.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..